# What can I do to make performance better when using a LABEL with large amount of text in Xamarin.Forms on Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been happily using a "Label" to display small to medium multi-line text with formatting.  But I have found that when the text gets large, even if not formatted, that the user interface to my app gets terribly unresponsive.  For example, I have tabs, and it takes a long time to switch tabs, and entering data into an unrelated Entry field is unbearably slow.

When I say "large", for example, 500K (14,000 lines) of text (in this case, unformatted).  This results in in 15 second delay when switching to or through the tab that has the large Label field.  Smaller amounts of text seem to work better -- 200K is about a 3 second delay, and 50K has no noticeable delay.

For reference, I've tried changing to an Editor control instead (again, using unformatted text), and it works fine, no noticeable delay.   I prefer the Label control, though:

- It naturally handles formatted text (I really need to be able to display some bits of text with colored background).
- It has a slider indication to the side (EDIT: no it doesn't, I forgot, I have a ScrollView wrapped around it)

Is there anything that can be done with this control, or an alternate, to make it work better with large amounts of text?

Comment: if I had to display a huge amount of text I would probably do it in a browser control.  Putting 500k of data in a Label is insane.

Comment: You mean like a WebView in Xamarin.Forms?  I could give that a try.  Too bad it won't directly deal with the "formatted text", though.